# Converting a WinForms form to WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I've written a media player application in C#, and I was wondering if there was any way to use WPF to change the border of the form without converting the whole project over to WPF. I'm asking this because I only have 2 and a half days to get the border changed, and I don't think converting the whole project over would be possible in that amount of time (I don't think 2 days would be long enough to learn the amount required for a port to WPF). Would it be simpler to try and change the border in C#?

Comment: I prefer to convert your application to WPF. It is not just a border. You can do many other things which you can't do in WinForms.

Comment: Can you show us your UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove the border of the form.

```
form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
```

Then, change the background of the form to an image you create that has a custom border in the image.

```
form.BackgroundImage = image;
```

This will get you where you need to be, in the short term.  In the long run, you are better off biting the bullet and switching to WPF if this is a project you will be maintaining and adding features to.

Comment: Not sure if that would be viable, it still has to have the regular close, maximize, and minimize buttons. Would those be kept if the border is gone?

Comment: You could always design your own buttons and place them in the form to handle those operations, it certainly would be quicker than converting to WPF.

Comment: That sounds like the best plan as far as time-constraints go. Thanks for the ideas!

Answer (score 1):

Use a [WindowsFormsHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.aspx) to host your WinForms form in a WPF window/application. Then you can have a WPF border for the WindowsFormsHost control.

You will only need to know WPF at a hello-world level and all of the application logic can stay inside the WinForms form.